# Given a walk between two vertices can you always find a trail between those two same vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

I want to prove this proposition that intuitively seems true.

Let me first start by defining both walk and trail as I'm not studying graph theory in english and I'm not 100% sure if these are the correct terms for what I want to say.

Given a graph G,

A walk is a succession of vertices and and edges of the following form, $r=x_0a_1x_1\cdots x_{l-1}a_lx_l$ where $l$ (the number of edges) is the length of the walk.

A trail is when a walk has no repeated edges.

Given this two definitions, let $r=x_0a_1x_1\cdots x_{l-1}a_lx_l$ be a walk with length $l$ from the vertex $k$ denoted by $x_0$ to the vertex $j$ dentoted by $x_l$.

In order to find a trail from $k$ to $j$ with the elements of $r$, I need to find a subsuccession of $r$ starting in $k$ and finishing in $j$ that has no repeating edges.

To do this, as there's no restrictions over $r$, I first take a subsuccession of the original path that only crosses the initial and final vertices once (starts in $k$ and finishes in $j$). I can build this new walk the following way,

I define $x_f \in r$ such that $f=\max\{n \in \mathbb N : x_f \in r \textrm{ and } x_f=x_l\}$ and I build the new walk $\hat r =x_0a_1x_1\cdots x_{f-1}a_fx_f$

Now, I define $x_i \in \hat r$ such that $i=\min\{n \in \mathbb N : x_i \in \hat r \textrm{ and } x_i=x_0\}$ and build the new walk $\bar r =x_ia_{i+1}x_{i+1}\cdots x_{f-1}a_fx_f$

I'm not sure if this previous step is necesary for the rest of the proof but thinking about it i thought that having the ending and starting points appear more than once could give some problems and as I only want to prove that there's at least one path with the elements in the original walk, this doesn't restrict the hypothesis.

Now that i have the shortened walk, I have to find a way to "remove" the extra edges. The way I thought of this by intuition is that if a walk crosses a certain edge and then it crosses it again after som extra steps, those extra steps between the first and last time it crosses the edge can be removed (its a loop, no matter how long it is you end up back going through the same edge). However, if two edges are the same, as the graph is not directional, the walk could be going in same or different directions and I have to treat both cases differently.

I propose the following process to build the path from the given walk $\bar r = r_0$.

1-Let $p_m=i+m$ with $1\leq m \leq f-i$ and let $m=1$ for the first    step

2-While $m\leq f-i$ repeat:

2.1-Given $a_p$ the p-th edge in the walk, define $a_c \in r_{m-1}$ with $c=\max\{n\in \mathbb N : a_n \in r_{m-1} \textrm{ and } a_n=a_p \}$

2.2-If $c=p$ then do nothing and skip to 2.4

2.3-If $a_p$ appears in $r_{m-1}$ as $xa_py$ and $a_c$ appears in $r_{m-1}$ as $xa_cy$ then define the succession $r_m$ as $r_{m-1}$ with the subsuccession $a_px_{p+1}a_{p+1}\cdots x_{c-1}$ removed

2.3-If $a_p$ appears in $r_{m-1}$ as $xa_py$ and $a_c$ appears in $r_{m-1}$ as $ya_cx$ then define the succession $r_m$ as $r_{m-1}$ with the subsuccession $x_pa_px_{p+1}a_{p+1}\cdots x_{c-1}a_c$ removed

2.4-Add one to $m$ and repeat step 2

3-You are left with $r_m$ a subsuccession built with the verices and edges from $r$ where the starting point is $k$, the ending point is $j$ and no edges are repeated

Therefore the walk built with this method is a trail from the edge $k$ to the edge $j$

I'd like to know wether this constructive proof is right and any sugestions anyone might have to improve it.

I apologize in advance for the notation, my discrete maths professor has given us no proves on the topics of graphs and I have no idea on what notation is formaly used.

Sorry too for any grammar or spelling mistakes I might have made, english is not my first language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the title of your question, you seem to have interchanged the words "trail" and "walk".

Comment: If you just want to prove the proposition and don't insist on a construction, you could simply argue that a $u,v$-walk of minimum length can have no repeated vertices and therefore no repeated edges. (A walk with no repeated vertices is usually called a "path" in English, sometimes a "simple path".)

Comment: Just check if there is a vertex appearing twice, if so collapse everything between the instances. And repeat this process. It's a silly theorem really, your proof is way too wooly for its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The magic words are "breadth first search". The graph is connected. Make the first vertex have depth $0,$ its neighbors are depth $1,$ their neighbors (the ones that have not been seen before) are depth $2,$ and so on. Eventually the second vertex will be reached, and the path of strictly increasing depth will be a "trail".